# sql inner join on blank table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have a complicated query for simple thing, but I have managed to make it to work. The query works when idclient is 1, but when idclient is 5 there is a problem.

Problem is that that client didn't order anything, he just paid some amount. So there isn't a.price, practically whole table is blank, and I want result like -1200,00 or paid amount in minus. My problem is that first part of table does not exist so inner join is impossible, and there for second part is also non existing. Any suggestion for a "quick fix"? :)

```
SELECT SUM(a.price) - s.pay AS Remain 
FROM   (SELECT name, 
               ( quantity * itprice ) * ( 100 - percent ) / 100 AS price, 
               idclient 
        FROM   (SELECT order.iditem     AS ID, 
                       item.name, 
                       SUM(order.quant) AS quantity, 
                       order.percent, 
                       item.itprice, 
                       order.idclient 
                FROM   item 
                       inner join order 
                               ON order.iditem = item.id 
                WHERE  ( order.idclient = 1 ) 
                GROUP  BY order.iditem, 
                          order.percent, 
                          item.name, 
                          item.itprice, 
                          order.idclient) AS X) AS a 
       inner join (SELECT SUM(amount) AS Pay, 
                          idcom 
                   FROM   payed 
                   WHERE  ( idcom = 1 ) 
                   GROUP  BY idcom) AS s 
               ON a.idclient = s.idcom 
GROUP  BY s.idcom, 
          a.idclient, 
          s.pay
```

(there is maybe some typing error in code, but don't bother because I have translated my original code, so maybe some letter is lost in translation. Code is correct)

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  There is probably an easier way to express what you want to do.  A SQL Fiddle is also a good idea.

Comment: Example: someone order 15 apple (which have price and discount etc), and a.price do the math for final price. That same person pay 100, than 200, than 500, and s.pay sum all that. Difference between that two is what I want to be shown. Problem is when someone do not order anything, but just pay for some amount. Then his table do not exist. And than my final result is one blank table. And I want to be - amount of payed cash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this always just fetching one row? At least it looks like it, and if that's the case you could just use variables with something like this:

```
declare @price decimal(10,2) = 0, @payment decimal(10,2) = 0

SELECT 
    @price = SUM(order.quant * item.itprice ) * ( 100 - order.percent ) / 100)
FROM
    item 
    inner join order 
        ON order.iditem = item.id 
WHERE
    order.idclient = 1 

SELECT 
    @payment = SUM(amount)
FROM   
    payed 
WHERE
    idcom = 1

select @price - @payment
```

Comment: mate, you are genius, I didn't even try with variables. This is so much easier. There is still need to use isnull(@Price,0) at the end, but now it is working. Thank you very much.